# How to use guid as primary key column (identity) in entity framework 5 with default value newid()?

Tags: entity-framework-5

i use Entity Framework 5.0 by "Model First". In 4.x there is a bug: the designer can't handle primary column guid with identy and defaultValue: "newid()" (source: http://leedumond.com/blog/using-a-guid-as-an-entitykey-in-entity-framework-4/)

Is it still not possible to use this in EF5? What is the problem to transform c# guid to sql "uniqueid" ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This worked for me doing database-first, but may help you after you've created your database -

You can update the table and set the default value as `newid()` using Server Management Studio (not through EF).

Then in the EF model, update the `StoreGeneratedPattern` from `none` to `Identity`.

2013 edit:
For completeness, in EF 5.0 Codefirst, you can specify the following data annotation:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Guid TableIdColumn { get; set; }
```